# Symfony admin generator : filter contents of combobox

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm building a blog engine to learn symfony.

I have an admin page where logged in authors can add "author comments" under any published content, using a combobox to choose the content title.

How can I filter the items in the combobox, to only show Contents written by that author ?
Should I create a new widget, how ?

Edit : should I use a textbox with some sort of autocomplete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you use doctrine. If you check the [source of sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/widget/sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice.class.php#L33) you'll see it accepts a `query` parameter that it will use to fetch the items displayed.

Create a `Doctrine_Query` object in your form's `configure` method, filter it for the current user's articles, and pass it via this option to the widget. And make sure you do the same with the validator.